# Provide thread private preallocated buffer to a parallelized for() loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, openmp

My program contains a for() loop that processes some raw image data, line by line, which I want to parallelize using OpenMP like this:

```
...
#if defined(_OPENMP)
        int const  threads = 8;
        omp_set_num_threads( threads );
        omp_set_dynamic( threads );
#endif
        int line = 0;
#pragma omp parallel private( line )
        {
            // tell the compiler to parallelize the next for() loop using static
            // scheduling (i.e. balance workload evenly among threads),
            // while letting each thread process exactly one line in a single run
#pragma omp for schedule( static, 1 )
            for( line = 0 ; line < max; ++line ) {
                // some processing-heavy code in need of a buffer
            }
        } // end of parallel section
....
```

**The question is this:**

Is it possible to provide an individual (preallocated) buffer (pointer) to each thread of the team executing my loop using a **standard OpenMP pragma/function** (thus eliminating the need to allocate a fresh buffer with each loop)?

Thanks in advance.

Bjoern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be understanding you wrong, but I think this should do it:

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
    unsigned char buffer[1024]; // private

    // while letting each thread process exactly one line in a single run
    #pragma omp for // ... etc
    for(int line = 0; line < max; ++line ) {
          //...
    }
}
```

If you really meant you want to share the same buffer for different parallell blocks, you'll have to resort to thread-local storage. (Boost as well as C++11 have facilities for making that easier to do (more portably too) than directly using [TlsAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and friends).

**Note** that this approach replaces some of the thread-safety checking burden back on the programmer because it is perfectly possible to have different `omp parallel` sections running at the same time, especially when they are being nested.

Consider that parallel blocks could be nesting at runtime, even though they are not *lexically* nested. In practice that is usually not good style - and often results in poor performance. However, it is something you need to be aware of when doing this).

Comment: The problem here is that the necessary buffer might be too big for the stack, especially as we're using multiple threads. Does adding 'buffer' to the 'omp parallel private' #pragma work for pointers as well?

Comment: IIRC `private` works for /names/ (identifiers). Regardless, I doubt you have to specify it. In my experience, variables declared _inside_ the parallel section are per-thread. So yes, feel free to just declare `std::vector<...> buffer` or new it up. Don't forget to delete it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will give this a shot, first thing tomorrow =).

Answer (score 4):

There is `threadprivate`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z1788dd

```
static int buffer[BUFSIZE];
#pragma omp threadprivate(buffer)
```

This pragma works on a global/static variable, so you don't need to worry about the stack overflow. (In such a stack-overflow case, it's not a bad idea at all to increase the stack size by tweaking linker option.)

Note that compilers may have different implementation details for `threadprivate`. For example, VS 2010 compiler can't do make threadprivate if the variable has a constructor. However, Intel C/C++ compiler does this job greatly.

Using separate `omp parallel` and `omp for` is also good idea as sehe showed it. However, using `threadprivate` allows you to use `omp parallel for` directly.

FYI: Even if you need to allocate your own thread-local storage, in many case you don't actually need to call an OS-specific function call such as `TlsAlloc`. You may simply allocate an array of N of the data structures. And, then access them by using `omp_get_thread_num` that gives thread ID from 0 to N-1. Of course, you must consider false sharing by inserting a padding to ensure each data structure should be aligned to a different cache line (mostly modern CPU caches have 64-byte cache line).

Comment: +1 for the omp_get_thread_num approach. This solution is more along the lines of what I originally had in mind. Looks like we are putting together a decent question here after all =)...